# Java - Array and input file reader

Tags: java, arrays

The program compiles but the output is wrong. Upon reading all of the data from baseball.txt, the program should display each Player team number, and the Baseball total number of hits, the total number of walks and the total number of outs that were stored on the input lines of the file.

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
// java class for file I/O
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// declaration of the class
public class Baseball
{

    // declaration of main program
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    // 1. connect to input file
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("baseball.txt"));

    // objects used to store data

    int number = 0,         // number, hits, walks, outs
        hits, 
        walks,
        outs,
        players;


    // 2. output descriptive messages
    System.out.println("This program tracks a baseball player's number "
                         + "and their\nnumber of hits, walks and outs for "
                         + "each game in a season.\n");

    // 3. input the number of players

    players = fin.nextInt();

    // 4. declare an array of players
    Player[] teamArray = new Player[players];

    // 5. loop over teamsize
    // 5a. instantiate the i'th team member
    for(int i = 0; i < teamArray.length; i++){
        teamArray[i] = new Player();
    }


    // 6 loop on end of file
    while (fin.hasNext())
        {
        // 6a. input the team number
               number = fin.nextInt();
           // 6b. input the player's hits
               hits = fin.nextInt();
           // 6c. input the player's walks
               walks = fin.nextInt();
           // 6d. input the player's outs
               outs = fin.nextInt();
           // 6e. update player attribute hits
                teamArray[players-1].getHits();
                teamArray[players-1].setHits(hits);
           // 6f. update player attribute walks
                teamArray[players-1].getWalks();
                teamArray[players-1].setWalks(walks);
           // 6g. update player attribute outs
                teamArray[players-1].getOuts();
                teamArray[players-1].setOuts(outs);

       }


    // display the results
    System.out.println("\n\nPlayer\tHits\tWalks\tOuts\n" 
                      + "------\t----\t-----\t----\n");
    // 7. loop over team size
    for (int t = 0; t < teamArray.length; t++)
        if (teamArray[t] == null)
        {
            System.out.println(" " + (t+1) + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + "0");
        }
        else
            System.out.println(" " + (t+1) + "\t" + teamArray[t]);


    // 8. disconnect from input file
    fin.close();

    } // end of main
} // end of the class
```

Here is the Player.java

```
// declare the class Player 
public class Player {



    // declare the attribute variables
    private int hits;
    private int walks;
    private int outs;


    // implement the default constructor
    public Player(){
        hits = 0;
        walks = 0;
        outs = 0;
    }


    // implement an extractor for each attribute variable
    public int getHits()
    {
         return hits;
    }

    public int getWalks()
    {
        return walks;
    }

    public int getOuts()
    {
        return outs;
    }
    // implement a mutator for each attribute variable
    void setHits(int hitsInt)
    {
        hits = hitsInt + hits;
    }

    void setWalks(int walksInt)
    {
        walks = walksInt + walks;
    }

    void setOuts(int outsInt)
    {
        outs = outsInt + outs;
    }
    // overload toString to support output of attribute values
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = new String();
        s = hits + "\t" + walks + "\t" + outs;
        return s;
    }

  // end of the class 
}
```

Here is Baseball.txt

```
20
1 2 2 2
20 0 5 1
2 0 0 6
18 4 2 0
3 2 1 3
4 1 2 3
7 0 0 3
8 1 4 1
9 3 2 1
10 2 2 2
11 6 0 0 
12 2 2 2
2 0 5 1
20 0 0 6
17 4 2 0 
4 2 1 3
3 1 2 3
7 0 0 3
```

Comment: What is it outputting?

Comment: This program tracks a baseball player's number and their
number of hits, walks and outs for each game in a season.



Player Hits Walks Outs
------ ---- ----- ----

 1 0 0 0
 2 0 0 0
 3 0 0 0
 4 0 0 0
 5 0 0 0
 6 0 0 0
 7 0 0 0
 8 0 0 0
 9 0 0 0
 10 0 0 0
 11 0 0 0
 12 0 0 0
 13 0 0 0
 14 0 0 0
 15 0 0 0
 16 0 0 0
 17 0 0 0
 18 0 0 0
 19 0 0 0
 20 30 32 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
// 6e. update player attribute hits
teamArray[number-1].setHits(hits);
// 6f. update player attribute walks
teamArray[number-1].setWalks(walks);
// 6g. update player attribute outs
teamArray[number-1].setOuts(outs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all the data into `teamArray[player-1]`, not into each individual player.

Create a temporary variable outside the `while` loop and increment the counter at each iteration.

```
int counter = 0;
// 6 loop on end of file
while (fin.hasNext())
    {
    // 6a. input the team number
           number = fin.nextInt();
       // 6b. input the player's hits
           hits = fin.nextInt();
       // 6c. input the player's walks
           walks = fin.nextInt();
       // 6d. input the player's outs
           outs = fin.nextInt();
       // 6e. update player attribute hits
           teamArray[counter].setHits(hits);
       // 6f. update player attribute walks
           teamArray[counter].setWalks(walks);
       // 6g. update player attribute outs
           teamArray[counter].setOuts(outs);
           counter++;
   }


// display the results
```